# Behavior of block elements in html

Tags: html, css

I have two section elements with ids container1,container2 respectively.Both have an ul element each as their first child. section#container1 has a border.

- If I set a margin for the ul elements, for section#container1(which
  has a border) the margin is inside the container, for
  section#container2, which has no child before ul element, the margin
  is outside the container.
- This happens for any first child of a parent, when the parent does not have its dimensions set.

The [jsbin link of the page](http://output.jsbin.com/huqomo).
The [screenshot of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2czB.png)
My question is regarding the behavior of block elements. I understand    this is very basic.

1. If we do not set height or width of a parent block element, the
   margin we set for the first child is rendered as if it is set for the
   parent.
2. But if we have a border, then in that case the margin is set inside
   the parent container and the container expands.Why is it so ?

Can any one please explain this behavior ? If you have any resource explaining such a basic behavior, please do point to that.There are many such small behaviors present, which is not mentioned in any tutorials. If any one has a list of such small things or something you learned by developing web pages please provide a link or mention in the comments or answers. This would be really helpful for beginners.

Comment: have you read [block level elements and inline elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're experiencing "collapsing margins". One of the rules of collapsing margins is that a first child's top and bottom margin will not push the child away from it's container, but rather the margin will be applied to the outside of the container. It's just a rule in CSS. Some of the things you can do to the container to make this rule not apply are

- Add a border
- Add padding
- Add `overflow: auto`

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing